# QGIS not binding value from field to widget in my custom form (Qt Designer)

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I have created a custom form in QT Designer with a QSpinBox and a QLineEdit. 
I named the objects the same as the column names so that qgis can bind the values.

Added the .ui to a layer.

The widgets are displayed with the value defined in the value field in QT Designer:

[image]

and I can edit the value. If I accept and reopen the form I always see the value in QT Designer but not the value I previously edited.

There must be something I am missing.

I am using QGIS 2.12. I have to use this version for now.

Comment: Did you name the QT-control the same as the columnname? This is how the databinding is mapped.

Comment: yes, sorry, forgot to tell it in the OP. Edited

Comment: can you include screenshots from the attribute properties and qt creator that demonstrate the question by Jakob?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn trust me, I am doing it right, with QTextEdit it works like a charm

Comment: There are different spinboxes for integers and doubles, maybe it's related to this? I just wanted to have as much information available here to get you a solution.